# Typing a large size block matrix on matlab

Tags: matlab

I am reading this paper [The iterative methods for computing the generalized inverse of the bounded linear operator between Banach spaces](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300309003257)

Where I came across a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{58\times 57}$ (Example 4.2) given as follows:
$A =\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   A_{11}  & A_{12}  & A_{13} \\
   A_{21}  & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
  \end{array}
\right) $ where $A_{ij}\in \mathbb{C}^{29\times 19} $. Author has given each $A_{ij}$ in this paper. I want to ask how to write this matrix on matlab? I am finding it difficult to type this matrix because of its large size and also I don't know how to type block matrices on matlab? Is there any alternate way to  write this matrix on matlab? Could anybody help me with this? I would be very much thankful.

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure whether this is what you are asking, but inputting a matrix in Matlab is quite straightforward:

```
A = [1+3i 2+4i 12-1i;
2 2i 2+2i]
```

Combining matrices is also quite simple:

```
B = [A A+1 2*A;
A-1 A-2 A+1i]
```